# Can't create Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

A client is trying to give me access to set up a Google Compute Engine instance. I have been given both Compute Admin and Compute Instance Admin (v1) roles. I can select her project when I log in to mine.

Further, I can access the Compute Engine area, which gives me the typical "Create", "Import", and "Take the Quickstart" options. When I click on "Create" I get the normal sidebar (new VM instance, new VM instance from template, and marketplace) but the form used to create does not appear and it's just the white background.

I've never had anyone give me access to their account so I am at a loss. I even had one of my other accounts give the other account access via the Computer Admin role and it worked fine. In other words, I had no problem giving the account access to one of my other accounts, but cannot seem to get access to her account.

A couple of things I have observed that may or may not be relevant:

1. I receive HTTP 403 responses for some resources when I try to access the page with the create instance form.
2. Her project is listed under "no organization".
3. She is using the free trial.
4. I have verified that the issue occurs in both Safari and Chrome.

Sorry I can't embed my images yet.

[Verified my assigned roles via screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouj73.png)

[Expected screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWzSn.png)

[Actual screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSdye.png)

Comment: I would recommend that you report this to our product team using [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to make sure that we investigate it further.

Comment: @MahmoudSharif I'll do that. I'm a little surprised it's not generating some kind of error message, so maybe that's a separate bug that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like permission issue, have you tried with the Role: "Compute Engine Admin Role" also grant the roles/iam.serviceAccountUser role to your account from the customer project take a look to the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/)

However how you shared from the screenshot with owner Role it should works.

Could you create a new project from the Client side then shared it to your account ?

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I was thinking that the next step(s) are either having her give me the owner role so I didn't have to keep asking her to do things through her or adding me to her gsuite. Of course, at this point I'm not sure either would actually work. I'm just trying not to push as much stuff off on her as I can.

Comment: for sure, test it and notify if it works. You said: "her gsuite" I mean it may be "her GCP project", just to be clear about the context.

Comment: Instead of giving her the "Project Owner" role, you should instead give her the "Project Viewer" role. With this, she will have [permissions for read-only actions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_roles).